Question About Using Offer Tokens in Billing Library 7
I am in the process of porting to Billing Library 7.
I was wondering, when performing a subscription via launchBillingFlow, can we use the offer token from a ProductDetails obtained during app startup? During app startup, we execute queryProductDetailsAsync once.
Or, do we need to ensure our ProductDetails are up-to-date by making an extra call to queryProductDetailsAsync to ensure the offer token is current, just before calling launchBillingFlow.
Thanks. So far, my observation is that the offer token remains the same all the time.
